# Form not sending message

Tags: javascript, heroku, cors, cors-anywhere

I use heroku CORS anywhere proxy to solve CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my form.

Now, my form showing message not send every time i tried to send a message. How can i solve this issue?

**My form:** [Demo](https://contactformerror.blogspot.com)

**Scripts:**

```
const blogId="xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

var contactForm = document.querySelectorAll(".contact-form-blogger");

function an(req) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(req)
    } catch (req) {
        return false
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < contactForm.length; i++) {
    var a = contactForm[i];
    a.addEventListener("submit", function (submitUrl) {
        submitUrl.preventDefault();
        var form = submitUrl.target;
        var req = new FormData(form),
            cH = "blogID=" + typeof blogId !== "undefined" ? blogId : "";
        req.forEach(function (cL, cK) {
            cH += "&" + encodeURIComponent(cK) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(cL)
        });
        submitUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.blogger.com/contact-form.do";
        req = new XMLHttpRequest;
        req.open("post", submitUrl, true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send(cH);
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var cK;
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    if (this.response != "") {
                        cK = an(this.responseText.trim());
                        if (cK.details.emailSentStatus == "true") {
                            form.reset();
                            var formSend = form.querySelector(".send-success");
                            if (formSend) {
                                formSend.style.display = "block";
                            }
                        } else {
                            var notSend = form.querySelector(".send-error");
                            if (notSend) {
                                notSend.style.display = "block";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the demo server as your proxy, which is rate-limited and not open. See [this announcement](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301) for details. You need to deploy it yourself and change the URL prefix to point to your version. The documentation, such as it is, can be found [at the bottom of the README](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). Advanced options are [here](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere#server). You're also posting to Blogger, which doesn't accept a POST at that path (returns a 405, method not allowed).